# Lenovo G510 Wi-fi driver problems

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, lenovo

I'm new with Linux. Here is my story: I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 today on my laptop Lenovo G510 with the BCM43142 wireless card...  Everything works well except the wi-fi that i can't use. I have tried `sudo apt-get bcmwl-kernel-source` and it doesn't work. I have a wired connection in case that I need to download something to help me out resolving this issue. Help me please!

PS: Maybe it will help:

```
lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network

08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:0611]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 11
    Region 0: Memory at b9500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
```

Comment: Make sure to format code correctly. It's really hard to get a grip of what's going on if Terminal output isn't correctly formatted. You should also proofread your post for spelling and/or grammatical errors. This isn't as important as most people will still understand you.

Comment: Whenever I see an issue with Broadcom wireless drivers, I link to the following guide: http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/367990 It covers almost everything that can cause problems with Broadcom. Try the suggestions over there and come back if it did not solve your problem and describe what you found out.

Comment: Fixed with: http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/amd64/bcmwl-kernel-source/download

Answer (score 3):

You apparently forgot 'install.' The command you want is:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Lenovo G510/I3 unit with Ubuntu 14.04.

I came across the same issue (wifi NOT working).And found the solution via an exhaustive search..

If you are interested in learning more about this issue - pls read through the below link (thanks to the community)

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers/60395#60395)

Short answer:

1) First run below on the terminal

lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Which will most likely give you the below output :

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)

2) In that pls note the PCI.ID & the Rev number.

```
 [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
```

3) Run Update :

sudo apt-get update

4) Then install the firmware pakage.

sudo apt-get install  bcmwl-kernel-source

5) Reboot the system

sudo reboot

After that your wireless will be working :-D

Good luck...

Ps - I believe your Bluetooth is also not working ? SO far trying to find a solution to that . DO let me know if you find a solution...